# With Ajax'd tab content my javascript in the tab isn't working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, tablefilter

So i'm using flowplayer's JqueryTools, tabs for navigation. 
Everything i'm loading is really simple. Mainly html tables and forms, and they work great.
Except on one page where i use [tablefilter.free.fr](http://tablefilter.free.fr/)'s tablefilter. The table filter will not load when i use the tabs. When i just open the php, then everything works fine.
I was wondering if anyone could tell me what i'm doing wrong here? I don't have much experience with javascript.

My main page is really simple.

```
<script blah blah blah tabletools.js>
<ul class="css-tabs">
<li><a href="ajax1.php">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax2.php">Second tab</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax3.php">An ultra long third tab</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="css-panes">
<div style="display:block"></div>
$(function() {

$("ul.css-tabs").tabs("div.css-panes > div", {effect: 'ajax', hitory: true});

});
</div>
```

And the ajax.php's are really simple tables, and for some reason the filter doesn't work when i load the page in the tabs. I load the filter with a class in the table, and i think that may be the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="TableFilter/tablefilter.js"></script>  

    <table id="table1" cellspacing="0" class="mytable filterable" >
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### jQuery Tools Tabs & TableFilter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('ul.css-tabs').tabs('div.css-panes > div', {
            effect: 'fade',
            history: true,
            onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
                // get the pane to be opened
                var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);
    
                // only load once. remove the if ( ... ){ } clause if you want the page to be loaded every time
                if (pane.is(':empty')) {
                    // load it with a page specified in the tab's href attribute
                    pane.load(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr('href'), function(){
                        setFilterGrid('table'+(i+1));
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

1. The above code should come after including jQuery, jQuery Tools Tabs, and TableFilter files.
2. Your tables should have an incremental id for each tab like `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `...`